# argparse causing error in cx_Freeze app

Tags: python, argparse, cx-freeze

I made two python programs A and B where both are packaged by cx_Freeze into different exe files.

Program A is the main program and B sits inside the `"Main Program folder/dummy_dist"`

A launches B using `subprocess.run()` like the following

`subprocess.run(["dummy_dist/dummy.exe", "--mode 1", "--pid " + str(os.getpid()), "--sid " + sid], cwd="dummy_dist")`

when I run this, the following error shows up

[image: cx_Freeze argparse error msg]

The only part of the error which is my code is the "line 45" which is

`args = parser.parse_args()`

and just for reference the code where I use argparse is this

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="-")

parser.add_argument('--mode', dest="mode", metavar='Program Mode', type=str,
                    help="")
parser.add_argument('--pid', dest="pid", metavar='PID', type=str, required=False)
parser.add_argument('--sid', dest="sid", metavar='SESSION_ID', type=str,
                    help="Active SESSION_ID", required=False)
```

The program runs fine when I run it as a .py file.

Can you guys please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So yeah... I found the bug

when calling

```
subprocess.run(["dummy_dist/dummy.exe", "--mode 1", "--pid " + str(os.getpid()), "--sid " + sid], cwd="dummy_dist")
```

I grouped the flag and the value in a single string when I should have separated them.

so it should be

```
subprocess.run(["dummy_dist/dummy.exe", "--mode", "1", "--pid", str(os.getpid()), "--sid", sid], cwd="dummy_dist")
```